# SharePoint ribbon icons disappeared

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

has anyone ever seen this before? all my icons in my ribbon have disappeared.

I'm using my own custom master page based on the minimal, all my ribbon code looks correct..

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I created a custom master page for SharePoint 2013 and had the same issue.  I was also missing the Site Settings, Share, Follow and Focus On Content icons.  Like you, the resolution was in the CSS.  I have a pretty extensive CSS Reset file and when I removed the CSS Link everything returned to normal.  In digging a little deeper here is the exact CSS style I needed to remove.

img
{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue after applying the responsive design and got this working in SharePoint 2013 :

```
.ms-cui-tabContainer img, #suiteBarButtons img {max-width:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you play around with the site permissions?

Just check if you are in the group of 'Style resource readers'.

Comment: not changed the permission's, I have a sub-site that still uses the V4 master page and that displays just fine. Weird one...

Comment: Found the answer...tracked it back to my 1140 responsive design CSS which had an entry of img,object, embed {
max-width: 99%;
}
Which sharepoint does not like...removed it and all back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and it was caused by the css that i had modified. Jeff pointed me in the right direction in that img {max-width:100%;} was the issue.

To correct this i created the following css at the end to overide the img resizing for the ribbon.

```
.ms-cui-topBar2 img {max-width:none;}
```